# how to access only specified portion of large n*m matrix as number of submatrices

Tags: java

suppose my .txt file is:
    data

```
1.0  3.1  2.1  3.4       
2.4  2.0  4.6  5.1       
0.2  3.3  4.7  9.1       
4.0  5.4  5.1  3.2        
6.1  2.1  6.4  2.6       
1.2  2.0  3.5  6.9       
3.1  2.5  4.6  9.8       
7.1  8.1  9.4  5.1       
12.1 3.1  2.5  2.4      
3.8  9.1  2.1  6.7
```

i m having the code to print that file in 2d n*m array.now i want to print the n*m submatrix of this file . for e.g
    data

```
1.0  3.1  2.1  3.4       
2.4  2.0  4.6  5.1       
0.2  3.3  4.7  9.1       
4.0  5.4  5.1  3.2
```

or 
i may want to print last three rows.pls help that would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should shoot the parameters n and m into the conditions in a nested for-loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        // access and print matrix[i][j]
    }
    // next line
}
```

Make sure you have lots of lovely bounds checking!

As for the offsets, you can initialise i and j to different values to achieve that. Again though, lots of bounds checking, or Java will scream obscenities at you.